# Need Help removing Mailbox (Architectural Mailbox 7500) from post

Tags: removal, mailbox

Trying to remove this mail box from the post.

[image]

There are five of these fasteners which I believe are holding the mailbox the mounting plate.

[image]

Here is an interior shot, and as you can see, it is not simply the process of unscrewing.
[image]

Appreciate your suggestions and feedback.

Comment: Do you want it to ever go on again?  Is the post one solid piece, or does it come apart?

Comment: I want to remove this mailbox permanently as I'm planning to install a new one, but didn't want to go through the hassle of removing the entire post.  The new box can sit atop of the existing plate.

Answer (score 1):

Those are pop rivets.  They are not for removing.

The product would have been sold with those permanent fasteners already installed.  The mailbox was installed on the post *after* those were attached, therefore they cannot be important to removing the mailbox from the post.

You can remove them *if you really want to* by drilling them out, however this will prove to be a waste of time.

Have you looked *inside* the mailbox proper?  Sometimes screws hide there.

Comment: I have checked and removed all other screws.  Appears the mailbox would slide off the base if these were removed, but now I guess I need to remove the entire plate and replace with a new one since I'm unable to remove these rivets.    https://uniim1.shutterfly.com/ng/services/mediarender/THISLIFE/000039305426/media/33030421094/medium/1463932543/enhance

Comment: It looks like the mailbox was originally attached with the screws in the image you there linked.  If you want to salvage that plate, they are soft aluminum rivets: a battery drill and 3/16" drill bit (or any size below about 3/8) should be adequate to drill it out.

Comment: My original intention was to salvage the original plate, but for $20, I can purchase a replacement one and keep the original mailbox intact, in case it ever needs to be sued again.  Thanks for your help regarding how to remove the rivets.